# Network adapter not working with Dell Vostro 1500 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell-vostro

I installed 14.04 on Dell Vostro 1500 but my network card isn't recognized.  How do I get this installed? Was installed via USB that worked with no issues when OS is ran from USB stick.

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN 
[14e4:4311] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
  Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/655838/edit) your question with `lspci -nnk | grep Network -A2` command output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to internet using some other adapter and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

If you do not have any other internet connection, then download these files.

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb
http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

Copy them to your home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo dpkg -i b43*.deb
tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

For 32-bit systems download http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_018-2_i386.deb

instead of the 64-bit package.

Comment: There is no other adapter

Comment: I updated the answer with offline guide.

Comment: Need files for i386

Comment: @tdaman I added the link to `i386`.